Select column name that has the maximum value (only list the column names once in the SQL query)
Input:

https://dbfiddle.uk/vPuEVN2v
For each row, I want to select the column name that has the maximum value:


What is the most succinct way to do that in SQLite, where the column names are only listed once in the SQL query?
For example, this is how it would be done in Oracle:
select objectid, max(col_name) keep (dense_rank first order by col_val desc) max_col_name
from employment_by_industry
unpivot (
  col_val
  for col_name in (
    agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew  --cols only listed once
  )
)
group by objected


You can unpivot a table with union all and use row_number for ordering within a group
select objectid, col_name
from (
  select objectid, row_number() over(partition by objectid order by col_val desc) rn, col_name
  from (
    select objectid, 'agr_forest_fish' col_name, agr_forest_fish col_val 
    from employment_by_industry

    union all

    select objectid, 'mining_quarry', mining_quarry
    from employment_by_industry
    ...
    ) t
)
where rn=1


@User1974 I see no problem. It should work as is.

One option is to use multi value aggregation with Max() function, join the values by objectid and use case expression to get specific name.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
CREATE TABLE employment_by_industry (
    objectid int,
    agr_forest_fish int,
    mining_quarry int,
    mfg int,
    electric int,
    water_sew int
);

INSERT INTO employment_by_industry (objectid, agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew)
VALUES (1, 20797, 428, 955, 30, 70);

INSERT INTO employment_by_industry (objectid, agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew)
VALUES (2, 6792, 6868, 8121, 238, 300);

INSERT INTO employment_by_industry (objectid, agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew)
VALUES (3, 8728, 2405, 1544, 43, 121);

/*    Y o u r    t a b l e    d  a t a :
objectid    agr_forest_fish  mining_quarry      mfg  electric   water_sew
--------    ---------------  -------------  -------  --------  ----------  
       1              20797            428      955        30          70
       2               6792           6868     8121       238         300
       3               8728           2405     1544        43         121    */

--      S Q L : 
Select i.objectid, 
       Case When e.value = i.agr_forest_fish Then 'agr_forest_fish'
            When e.value = i.mining_quarry Then 'mining_quarry'
            When e.value = i.mfg Then 'mfg'
            When e.value = i.electric Then 'electric'
            When e.value = i.water_sew Then 'water_sew'
       End as industry
From   employment_by_industry i
Left Join ( Select objectid, 
                   Max(agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew) AS value 
            From   employment_by_industry 
            Group By  objectid
          ) e ON (i.objectid = e.objectid)

/*    R e s u l t :
objectid  industry
--------  ------------------
       1  agr_forest_fish
       2  mfg
       3  agr_forest_fish     */

